# CUPS PPD - default InputSlot for specific paper formats

Tags: cups, ppd

I have a printer with multiple input slots. One slot contains A4 papers and one A3 papers. When printing A3, I need to manually select the desired input slot by supplying the InputSlot=Tray2 option. Is there a way to configure the slots in the printer's PPD (or anywhere else) so I don't have to tell the printer which slot to use every time I want to print?

For example: When printing A4, use Tray1, When printing A3, use Tray2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can add different profiles in CUPS for one printer.
Example: I have a Samsung color laser printer and use the default profile for color printing
and added a second profile for grayscale. Whenever I want to print I choose the default or the grayscale printer.

You can change this in the web frontend.

Change default profile (tray1):
Goto http://localhost:631/admin -> "Manage Printers" 
-> select printer -> select "Set Default Options" from dropdown -> select tray1 as default paper source -> "Set default options"

Add another profile (tray2):
Goto http://localhost:631/admin -> "Add Printer" -> select printer -> choose a different name and description
-> continue -> "Add printer" -> select tray2 as default paper source -> "Set default options"

Comment: Thanks, that should work. However, I would like just one profile and the tray should be selected based on the paper format.